# How do I filter rails objects by user's email address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I have the following model:

```
class Iosapp < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :active, :featured, :name, :partner

  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

I reference the user that is associated with an Iosapp object in the view by saying:

```
<%= @iosapp.user.email %>
```

In the controller, I currently have what is below.  But how do I change this so that it only returns objects that have a certain email address (test@test.com, for example)?

```
@iosapps = Iosapp.all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@iosapps = Iosapp.joins(:user).where(:users => {:email => 'test@test.com'}).all
```

**EDIT:**

Or if you want the user data returned with the iosapp data, then this:

```
@iosapps = Iosapp.includes(:user).where(:users => {:email => 'test@test.com'}).all
```

Comment: I get an error saying: no such column: user.email: SELECT "iosapps".* FROM "iosapps" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "iosapps"."user_id" WHERE "user"."email" = 'test@test.com'

Comment: it should be `users.email` not `user.email`, you might need to construct the join where like so `.where("users.email = ?", 'test@test.com')`

Comment: Fixed typo, try again. The typo was as house9 suggested.